# Php array: add values of key 'x' for the Same Values of key 'y'

Tags: php, arrays

How can I add values of **key 2** of *inner arrays* for the similar values of **key 0** of *inner arrays*.

Thanks for your help i'm stuck on this problem. Let me explain it, i have this kind of array.

```
  array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => float 10002
      1 => string 'xxxyyyy' (length=7)
      2 => float 5.00
      3 => float 0
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => float 10002
      1 => string 'xxxyyyy' (length=7)
      2 => float 5.00
      3 => float 4.25
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => float 10002
      1 => string 'xxxyyyy' (length=7)
      2 => float 5.00
      3 => float 0
  3 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => float 10010
      1 => string 'yyyyyyy' (length=7)
      2 => float 10.00
      3 => float 0
  4 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => float 10010
      1 => string 'yyyyyyy' (length=7)
      2 => float 10.00
      3 => float 1.85
  5 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => float 10010
      1 => string 'yyyyyyy' (length=7)
      2 => float 10.00
      3 => float 0
```

Is it possible to get this result (if key0 values are same of inner arrays then sum key2 values )

```
sum_key_2 = 15, for key_0 = 10002
sum_key_2 = 30, for key_0 = 10010
```

I tried this but not getting desired output:

```
$bill = 0; $sp_no = array();
foreach($data as $innerKey => $innerArray) {
  $sp_no[] = $innerArray[0];
}

foreach($data as $k => $val) {
  if ($sp_no[$k] == $val[0]) {
    $bill += $val[2];
  }
}
echo $bill;
```

Comment: I am voting to delete this closed page because the one answer that satisfied the task received a followup comment which suggests the desired result was not achieved.  Unclear [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can group them first using `key_0` as key then adding each corresponding `key_2` inside `key_0` group

```
$result = [];                            // Initialize result array
foreach ($data as $value) {              // Loop thru data array
    if (!isset($result[$value[0]])) {    // Check if key_0 is on result array
        $result[$value[0]] = $value[2];  // Create new with value of key_2
    } else {
        $result[$value[0]] += $value[2]; // Increment with value of key_2
    }
}

// Printing result
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    echo 'sum_key_2 = ' . $value . ', for key_0 =' . $key . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: how to sum key_3 as well. For e.g. `sum_key_2 = 15 & sum_key_3 = 4.25, for key_0 = 10002`?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this solution

I have assumed that you will be trying to match array[0] and array[2]

```
$fullArray = [
    0 =>
        [
            0 => 10002,
            1 => 'xxxyyyy',
            2 => 5.00,
            3 => 0,
        ],
    1 =>
        [
            0 => 10002,
            1 => 'xxxyyyy',
            2 => 5.00,
            3 => 4.25,
        ],
    2 =>
        [
            0 => 10002,
            1 => 'xxxyyyy',
            2 => 5.00,
            3 => 0,
        ],
    3 =>
        [
            0 => 10010,
            1 => 'yyyyyyy',
            2 => 10.00,
            3 => 0,
        ],
    4 =>
        [
            0 => 10010,
            1 => 'yyyyyyy',
            2 => 10.00,
            3 => 1.85,
        ],
    5 =>
        [
            0 => 10010,
            1 => 'yyyyyyy',
            2 => 10.00,
            3 => 0,
        ]
];

for($i = 0; $i < count($fullArray); $i++) {
    if($fullArray[0][$i] != $fullArray[2][$i]) {
        // do your logic here
    } else {
        //do else logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry u didn't get the question. I don't want to match 2 arrays. i want to match values of keys of inner arrays. For eg. values of key 0 are similar in first 3 arrays i.e. '10002', so add key 2 values of those first 3 arrays and so on